# SendKeys not recognize while should exist in context

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sendkeys

I want to send a `SendKeys` to a process in c#. I added `System.Windows.Forms`, I had this error then:

> C:\Users\user\Desktop\Project\Project\Workflow1.xaml : error XC1014: Assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' can not be resolved.  Please add a reference to this assembly in the project that is being built.

I did add reference for `System.Drawing`, but now for `SendKeys` I get:

> The name 'SendKeys' does not exist in the current context.

I opened up the `Object browser` in Visual studio, and `SendKeys` is existing :

```
public class SendKeys
    Member of System.Windows.Forms

Summary:
Provides methods for sending keystrokes to an application.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you add `using System.Windows.Forms` on top of your code?

Comment: don't why my comment disappeared, yes you can, i'll mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either add `using System.Windows.Forms` on top of your code, or directly use the namespace when using `SendKeys`: `System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys`